# MASM with VS 2019 integration

Tags: visual-studio, masm

I have set up a MASM assembly project with VS 2019.
the IDE give this error. "'﻿ml64.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command".
after turned on detailed log information, the IDE shown this

"C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\MASM>﻿ml64.exe", obliviously, the IDE was affixed a wrong path to ml64.exe.

"C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\MASM" is my solution folder

How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is my bad.
I have installed MASM32 SDK from ([www.masm32.com](http://www.masm32.com)) , and set System path
to include the SDK bin folder.

after removed the MASM32 SDK, my project worked.